# Showing Invalid Keyhash for facebook android when signed APK

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating facebook login in my application.

It worked perfect for development APK. but when i am generating a signed apk then it shows error for

```
Invalid keyhash.Thekeyhash ****************************doesnotmatchanystoredkeyhashes.Configureyourappkeyhashesat
```

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/*************/

I have integrated it several time and it worked fine for all rest apps but this time i cant identify what i have did wrong

Steps i followed.

-> Generate Signed APK Using New Fresh Key Store

-> The generated SHA1 Key and Key hash using same keystore file

-> I have configured the Key hash prompted in CMD in facebook developer account

-> Then i have installed app and i tried login using facebook from browser it worked fine

-> Then i have tried it from Facebook Android APP from my app and it promped me a above error . then i have copied a key hash from error message and configured in facebook developer account

But still it showing same error for same key hash which i have configured in developer account

I have tried changing Package name , facebook developer account and app also have generated key store and lot signed apk but still problem is appearing everytime

Please guide me on this.